# What are the 2 star level requirements in Empire Defense 2?

Tags: empire-defense-2

What are the requirements to achieve 2 or more stars on a level in Empire Defense 2? I've been looking but can't find anything. I've tried all sorts of things, but I get nothing more than 1 star as a result.

I tried the following in different combinations
- end with 3000 gold
- using only single unit
- using all available units
- end with general full health
- not using any path moves
- using all path moves
- strategic placement of units and path
- upgraded all units before adding new ones
- bought new units and another spot for them
- end each round with spare time

Comment: Hi @Dustin, you said you've tried "all sorts of things", but can you add more detail to your question, like what you've actually tried that hasn't worked for you? It'll help you get better answers if people know what you've already done that didn't help you. :)

Comment: There should be documentation and thats what im looking for, not guesses. Im guessing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess as I've just started playing the game, but 4 possible stars and 4 difficulty levels.

Comment: Good guess. I played on medium with same results. I bet its a combo of diff. plus stats

Comment: We're both right. You can achieve the potential 2,3,4 star rating based on the level of difficulty you choose. So if you play the most difficult, you could potentially receive 4 stars. Actually getting 4 stars depends on your playing stats like how much money you have after, life left on the general and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I just started playing this game and I'm surprised at how little information there is about it online. However, assuming the stars are determined the same way that "Power" is determined in arena battles, then according to the in game help (`http://121.52.212.203/td2/help/help.html`):

> Your power after an arena battle is determined by how many waves of
>   enemies you survived, how much HP your hero had left, your number of
>   units, and how much gold remained unused.

I imagine the difficulty is also taken into account for the stars.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned it is all based on difficulty. If you have no hits on your general and are on the highest difficulty you'll get 4 stars.

Answer (score 0):

That's all true. But it also depends on units used. Some levels require you to use monk or crossbow to win. difficulty corresponds with amount of stars possible. So easiest difficulty would only allow one star while hardest difficulty will get you 4.it is also possible to get full starts while your general has taken damage. So if you win a match and don't get full stars, this team will get you full stars : drummer, hammer, witch, archer, crossbow, taois priest.